# Overlayed seaborn distplots sharing x axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

sorry if this is too basic, this is my first question to the forum:

I'm using the titanic dataset for practice and

I'm trying to plot two distributions of the variable 'Age', one only with passengers that survived and another with the passenger that perished. But for some reason, they don't share the same x-axis when plotted together.

Here's my code so far:

```
df_age = df[df['Age'].notnull()]
dfage_survived = dfage[dfage.Survived == 1] 
dfage_perished = dfage[dfage.Survived == 0] 

sns.set(style="white", palette="muted", color_codes=True)
fig = plt.figure(constrained_layout=True, figsize=(8, 8))
spec = fig.add_gridspec(3, 2)

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(spec[0, 0])
ax1 = sns.barplot(x='Sex', y = 'Survived', data =df)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(spec[0, 1])
ax2 = sns.barplot(x='Embarked', y = 'Survived', data =df)
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(spec[1, 0])
ax3 = sns.barplot(x='Pclass', y ='Survived', data =df)
ax4 = fig.add_subplot(spec[1, 1])
ax4 = sns.barplot(x='SibSp', y ='Survived', data=df)
ax5 = fig.add_subplot(spec[2, :])
ax5_1 = sns.distplot(dfage_survived['Age'], kde = False, label = 'Survived')
ax5_2 = sns.distplot(dfage_perished['Age'], kde = False, label = 'Perished')
plt.legend(prop={'size': 12})
```

OUTPUT:
[OUTPUT:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mgej0.png)

Comment: The reason is that the bins of the histogram are dividing the range between the smallest and largest x into equal parts. Both sets have different minimal and maximal values. Moreover, your data is discrete, so the bin boundaries should best be placed inbetween the integer values. The solution is to set the bins explicitly: `sns.distplot(..., bins=np.arange(-0.5, 86, 5))` for both.

Answer (score 0):

You must set bins for each `sns.distplot` call, otherwise sns will set the bins for you, which are based on the minimum element and maximum element, and since these are different for perished and survived, the bars won't line up. Use the `bins` parameter to set appropriate bins (see here https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.distplot.html)

Answer (score 0):

The bins of the histogram are dividing the range between the smallest and largest x into equal parts. Both sets have different minimal and maximal values. Moreover, your data is discrete, so the bin boundaries should best be placed in-between the integer values. The  bins can be set explicitly: sns.distplot(..., bins=np.arange(-0.5, 86, 5)) for both.

A simpler approach, however, is to make use of Seaborn's `hue=` parameter to make seaborn take care of dividing the groups and creating both histograms in one go.

Note that `sns.distplot` has been replaced by `sns.histplot` in the latest version (0.11). If you want both histograms stacked, you can add the parameter `multiple='stack'`.

To obtain a stand-alone example, the code below uses the standard Seaborn Titanic dataset, which uses the column names in lowercase.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

df = sns.load_dataset('titanic')
sns.set(style="white", palette="muted", color_codes=True)
fig = plt.figure(constrained_layout=True, figsize=(8, 3))
spec = fig.add_gridspec(1, 2)

ax5 = fig.add_subplot(spec[0, :])
sns.histplot(df, x='age', bins=np.arange(-0.5, 86, 5), kde=False, hue='survived', legend=True, ax=ax5)
ax5.legend(['Yes', 'No'], title='Survived?', prop={'size': 12})
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]